# Mongo/Mongoose: Why does this query fail?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find documents in mongoDB that are older than a specific amount of time. 
Here is an example of a document in my database that should be returned,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc07ea943eeba155840b62f"),
    "name" : "test3",
    "value" : 3,
    "created_at" : {
        "$date" : 1556119209477
    },
    "updatedAt" : {
        "$date" : 1556119209477
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Here is the query I have so far....

```
Item.find({"created_at":{$lt:new Date(Date.now() - keys.anAmountOfMilliseconds)}}, (err, foundItems) => {
```

When run like this, the following error is returned: { CastError: Cast to date failed for value "Invalid Date" at path "created_at" for model "items"

When searching for documents using, createdAt or "createdAt", the query returns with nothing....

Comment: What does it contain `keys.anAmountOfMilliseconds`?

Comment: It contains a number. Like 1. Or 86400000 (how many milliseconds there are in a day.)

Comment: I think it is containing either undefined or something else other then date